# Characterization of operators which are scalar multiple of the identity

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a *finite-dimensional* *vector space* and $T$ be a *linear map* from $V$ to itself (in other words, it's an *operator* on $V$).

> I need to prove that $T$ is a scalar multiple of the identity (i.e. $T(v)=cv$ for all $v \in V$ and for some $c \in F$, the underlying field) *if* and *only if* $ST=TS$ for all operators $S$ on $V$.

Note that $ST=TS$ does not necessarily mean that they are both equal to $I$, the identity operator. The *only if* part is trivial. But I cannot see how to attack the *if* part. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Consider $S(x)=vv^\top x$ for every $v\in V$. Then $v$ is an eigenvector of $T$. multiples of the identity are the only operator that have every vector as eigenvectors.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Yes, exactly. Thanks for the link.